# VSTS - Unable to add video to test run attachments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am attempting to use the **Publish Test Results** VSTS task to add some failed test videos to each test run, however the file doesn't appear to be uploaded. Other files in the directory are attached.

At the end of my test run my results folder looks like the following...

[image]

My task is setup as follows....

[image]

And the output from a simple test run...

[image]

The .mp4 file is not being found/uploaded

I have a feeling this might be because attachments are only retrieved from within the folder `moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55`. If this is the problem then I'm unable to add to this folder in code as I'm not using MSTest.

If this is the issue, how else can I add attachments to this task?

Here is the log from the task...

```
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Publish Test Results'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeededOrFailed()
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeededOrFailed:
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[debug]Expanded: True
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[debug]Result: True
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Test Results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ==============================================================================
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z Description  : Publish Test Results to VSTS/TFS
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z Version      : 2.0.5
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613742)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.4016201Z ==============================================================================
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\Build Agent\_work
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CONFIGURATION
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_MERGETESTRESULTS
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PLATFORM
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PUBLISHRUNATTACHMENTS
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SEARCHFOLDER
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TESTRESULTSFILES
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TESTRUNNER
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TESTRUNTITLE
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6827935Z ##[debug]loaded 11
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]check path : C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\task.json
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\task.json
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]testRunner=VSTest
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]testResultsFiles=**\*.trx
**\*.html
**\*.log
**\*.mp4
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]mergeTestResults=false
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]platform=$(BuildPlatform)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]configuration=$(BuildConfiguration)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]testRunTitle=ThisIsThePublish
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]publishRunAttachments=true
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]searchFolder=C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a/Selenium/drop/Settings/Results Files
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]testRunner: VSTest
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]testResultsFiles: **\*.trx,**\*.html,**\*.log,**\*.mp4
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]mergeResults: false
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]platform: $(BuildPlatform)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]config: $(BuildConfiguration)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]testRunTitle: ThisIsThePublish
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]publishRunAttachments: true
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]defaultRoot: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a/Selenium/drop/Settings/Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.6984131Z ##[debug]pattern: '**\*.trx'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55 (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55.trx (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\RLoginLLL02LogoutofSEPA26042018074737.mp4 (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]10 results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]found 10 paths
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\**\*.trx'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]1 matches
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]pattern: '**\*.html'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55 (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7140651Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55.trx (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\RLoginLLL02LogoutofSEPA26042018074737.mp4 (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]10 results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]found 10 paths
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\**\*.html'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]2 matches
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]pattern: '**\*.log'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55 (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55.trx (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\RLoginLLL02LogoutofSEPA26042018074737.mp4 (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]10 results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]found 10 paths
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\**\*.log'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]2 matches
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]pattern: '**\*.mp4'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55 (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM (directory)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55.trx (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\RLoginLLL02LogoutofSEPA26042018074737.mp4 (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]  C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log (file)
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]10 results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]found 10 paths
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]adjustedPattern: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\**\*.mp4'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7296533Z ##[debug]1 matches
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]6 final results
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Detected 6 test result files
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]PublishTestResults.OverrideExeFlow=undefined
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]OS type: Windows_NT
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]which 'C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]found: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]which 'C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]found: 'C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe'
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://smartassessor.visualstudio.com/
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]SystemVssConnection auth param AccessToken = ********
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]System.TeamProject=Smart End Point Assessment
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Build.RequestedFor=Matt O'Connor
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Build.BuildId=4693
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Build.BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/4693
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Release.ReleaseUri=vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/1668
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Release.EnvironmentUri=vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/6305
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7453158Z ##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=C:\Build Agent\_work\_temp
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7609359Z ##[debug]C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe arg: ["@C:\\Build Agent\\_work\\_temp\\270b7f90-4926-11e8-aac5-6b3082964456.txt"]
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7609359Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7609359Z ##[debug]arguments:
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7609359Z ##[debug]   @C:\Build Agent\_work\_temp\270b7f90-4926-11e8-aac5-6b3082964456.txt
2018-04-26T07:48:04.7609359Z [command]"C:\Build Agent\_work\_tasks\PublishTestResults_0b0f01ed-7dde-43ff-9cbb-e48954daf9b1\2.0.5\modules\TestResultsPublisher.exe" "@C:\Build Agent\_work\_temp\270b7f90-4926-11e8-aac5-6b3082964456.txt"
2018-04-26T07:48:05.2572361Z ##[debug]UseTestResultsPublisherExe feature flag is off
2018-04-26T07:48:05.2728540Z ##[debug]rc:20000
2018-04-26T07:48:05.2728540Z ##[debug]success:true
2018-04-26T07:48:05.2728540Z ##[debug]Exit code of TestResultsPublisher: 20000
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0374311Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\RLoginLLL02LogoutofSEPA26042018074737.mp4'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0530147Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0530147Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0530147Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55.trx'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0530147Z ##[debug]Setting run start and finish times.
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0530147Z ##[debug]Attachment location: C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0686514Z ##[debug]Adding run level attachment: C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0686514Z ##[debug]Adding run level attachment: C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0686514Z ##[debug]Total test results: 2
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0686514Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[results.publish type=VSTest;mergeResults=false;platform=$(BuildPlatform);config=$(BuildConfiguration);runTitle=ThisIsThePublish;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\RLoginLLL02LogoutofSEPA26042018074737.mp4,C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html,C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log,C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55.trx,C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.html,C:\Build Agent\_work\r1\a\Selenium\drop\Settings\Results Files\moconnor_SEPASELENIUMVM 2018-04-26 07_47_55\In\SEPASELENIUMVM\Selenium.SEPA.Test_SpecFlow_2018-04-26T074734.log;]
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.124.0
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[debug]Unable to publish telemetry due to lower agent version.
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]
2018-04-26T07:48:06.0999163Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2018-04-26T07:48:06.3342778Z Publishing test results to test run '4158'
2018-04-26T07:48:06.3342778Z Test results remaining: 2. Test run id: 4158
2018-04-26T07:48:07.0217578Z ##[debug]Uploading test run attachements individually
2018-04-26T07:48:07.3967661Z Published Test Run : https://smartassessor.visualstudio.com/Smart%20End%20Point%20Assessment/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=4158&_a=runCharts
2018-04-26T07:48:07.3967661Z ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
2018-04-26T07:48:07.3967661Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2018-04-26T07:48:07.3967661Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Test Results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t upload test attachments through Publish Test Results task. (There is the warning in the log)

You can upload attachments to test run through [Test Run Attachment REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/attachments/create%20test%20run%20attachment) (e.g. programming with PowerShell), to get the test run id, you may need to get [build log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20build%20log)/[release log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20task%20log) first, then get the test run id from log)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to get the test run id based on the release id but the 'Runs -> Query' endpoint doesn't appear to be filtering on the values I supply in the url parameters. E.g. the following `https://smartassessor.visualstudio.com/Smart End Point Assessment/_apis/test/runs?releaseIds=1678&api-version=5.0-preview.2` seemingly returns every test run against that project, not specific to the release id supplied. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Konzy262 That REST API has the issue. I recommend that you can get the release log first, then analysis the log to retrieve test run id through PowerShell.